# Is there is a way to get the associated MN's to an access point?

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I'm using INET and want to simulate a scenario that consist of three Access Points (AP)and one Mobile Node (MN), may each AP has other associated MNs on its range, what I want is : while the MN (in my scenario) move around and get beacons from the APs, before association with APs can I get the number of other MNs that associated with each AP? I explored many source codes and I found MACaddressTable and something like that stalist in ieee80211MgmtAP ,are they useful for me? and use them as total Number of associated MNs, 
then How can I evaluate the length of stalist? or MACaddressTable?

else I must put a counter to count that at on AP side and emit it through beacon frame? if so please give me some guides or shortcuts 
regards ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In IEEE 802.11 AP **does not** send information about the number of associated stations. Therefore in order to broadcast this information you have to introduce your own modification/extension into IEEE 802.11 protocols, for example a new field in beacon frame.
2. In INET model AP stores own stations in `staList` map. To locally calculate the current number of associated station you can use the following code:

   `STAList::const_iterator it;
   int assocSta = 0;
   for (it = staList.begin(); it != staList.end(); ++it) {
      if (it->second.status == ASSOCIATED) 
          assocSta++;
   }`

If you want modify standard beacon frame, firstly, you have to assume where exactly you want to add a new field in beacon frame, e.g. after which existing field, as well as what size this filed should have. Then:

- add a new filed (for example  `int noOfAssociatedStas;`) in class `Ieee80211BeaconFrameBody` in file `Ieee80211MgmtFrames.msg` and correct length in `Ieee80211BeaconFrame` definition
- in `Ieee80211Serializer.cc` after `else if (dynamic_cast<const Ieee80211BeaconFrame *>(pkt))` add serialization of a new field, for example:

  `unsigned int numSta = Frame->getBody().getNoOfAssociatedStas();
   b.writeByte(numSta); // assuming that the new field is 1 byte length`
- in `Ieee80211Serializer.cc` in `deserialize` add deserialization of a new field, after `case 0x80: //ST_BEACON` for example: 
  `unsigned int numSta = b.readByte();`

Please note that the place of adding the new filed (second bullet) must exactly match the place of reading it (third bullet).

Comment: your answer is quit useful, about part one if I want to modify the current beacon structure is it require to change only in beacon frame , add an other field to it as  noOfAssociatedStas? and a function to get it?  is its enough ? or their is many places that I must to take care of it?

Comment: I have just extended my answer according to your additional question.

Comment: I tried to implement new field to beacon frame, but the places that you are pointed to it, I couldn't find them, as I use INET V 2.6 your answer may be according to other versions, for example there is no file named Ieee80211MgmtFrames.msg, also Ieee80211Serializer.cc .. can you give me away to do it... regards...

Comment: My answer is for INET 3.0. There were significant changes in IEEE 802.11 between version 2.6 and 2.99 and 3.0. Could you start using version 3.0, or not?

Comment: actually I started with it v3.0, but as I posted an other question about rxPower() and I couldn't resolve it, so I went back to v2.6, in v26 the rxPower function is work properly... if you can solve this problem (as I see is a Bug, because the same function but  it always return zero) I will use v3.0 thanks anyway..